# Outputting the Start Date & End Date Given the Week Number and the Year

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, week-number

I'm having a bit of trouble trying to get my `=arrayformula()` function to output the right response and would appreciate some help!

### Here is the scenario:

Users lock in their data metrics in the `'!Revenue Log'`. The `TempDataSet` sheet runs a query of that data and I've written some extra functions to calculate other metrics for future graphing. Dataset with Function is the desired output but unsure how to have it automatically fill.

In the highlighted section, I am trying to get the `Start Date` and the `End Date` given the `Week Number` and the `Year`. So it would look like this:

Example:  Given Week 14 and Year: 2021 --> Output: Start Date: March 29th | End Date: April 4th

This is the formula I used for retrieving the Start Date:

```
=MAX(DATE(R2,1,1),DATE(R2,1,1)-WEEKDAY(DATE(R2,1,1),2)+(S2-1)*7+1)
```

This is the formula I used for retrieving the End Date:

```
=MIN(DATE(R2+1,1,0),DATE(R2,1,1)-WEEKDAY(DATE(R2,1,1),2)+S2*7)
```

---

In the `TempDataSet` sheet, I am trying to create an `arrayformula()` function that automatically uses the two functions in the appropriate cells so that it autofill with the output of the function.

You can see the results on the `Weekly Hourly Rate Timeline` sheet as if you select '2023' in A2, you will see the desired output, but if you select '2022' or '2021', you will see that the Start Date & End Dates do not match up correctly

Here is the link to the spreadsheet for anyone who needs a visual and wants to try and edit: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18AKrZrla3rSjFrhYErsg-tV07E-FUJzXUXEAyXWRER4/edit?usp=sharing

Please help if you can & thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach added to your [sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18AKrZrla3rSjFrhYErsg-tV07E-FUJzXUXEAyXWRER4/edit#gid=1435210134&range=AG2):

this is hard-coded for years `2021-2024`

```
=map(R2:R,S2:S,lambda(r,s,if(r="",,
let(a,sequence(1461,1,date(2021,1,1),1),b,filter(a,year(a)=r,weeknum(a,2)=s),text(min(b),"mmm dd")&" - "&text(max(b),"mmm dd")))))
```

[image]

Comment: The concatenation of the two dates separated with a comma I have already, what I referred to was that I need the function in the Start Date column and the End Date column to auto populate. I tried doing it with =arrayformula(), but it will not output the correct solution

So the Start Date column should produce a Date Given a Weeknumber and a Year (Example: Year: 2021 & Week Number: 14 should produce March 29th)

Comment: the formula produces both `start` and `end` dates independently based on `Columns R & S` and then concatenates them. It is not just appending existing start & end dates in `Columns T & U`. you can remove the `max` part in the formula for start_date and similarly remove `min` part to output end_date (arrayformula style ofcourse)

Comment: Wow okay that makes so much more sense! And I can replace the hard coded year of 2021 and replace it with the an entry given somewhere in the sheet. Thank you so much! Can I ask what the 1461 number in the sequence represents?

Comment: the dates considered for backend calculations are from `1-jan-2021` to `31-dec-2024` (1461 days)

Comment: But I need the function start year to be the first year of the date inputted by the user and so on

So in the sheet, I have April 2nd, 2021 as the first date so it should start in 2021. If the date was April 2nd 2020, then it should start in 2020.

As far as the end year, the end year would be based on the last entry of the user. So in this case, the last entry is Feb 25th 2023 so the end year would be 2023.

Comment: you may try: `=map(R2:R,S2:S,lambda(r,s,if(r="",,
let(a,sequence(days(date(year(max(C2:C)),12,31),date(year(min(C2:C)),1,1))+1,1,date(year(min(C2:C)),1,1),1),b,filter(a,year(a)=r,weeknum(a,2)=s),text(min(b),"mmm dd")&" - "&text(max(b),"mmm dd")))))`